# how to make a process Timer Interrupt?

Tags: c

I have a class assignment where I need to create code within premade functions that completes sets of test code, I am struggling with a process timer interrupt. this is what I am giving as instructions

```
/* processTimerInterrupt()
 * Tells the system that an interrupt occurred. 
 * Returns the PID of the new running process
 * or -1 if none are running
 */
int processTimerInterrupt(processStructure* ps);
```

And this is what I currently have

```
int processTimerInterrupt(processStructure* ps) {
    for(int i=0; i < NPROC; i++){
        if(ps->state[i] == RUNNING && ps->state[i+1] == EMBRYO){
            //printf("process pior %d + %d = i \t %d \n", ps->childern[i], i, ps->state[i]);
            return ps->childern[i];
        }else if(ps->state[i] == RUNNABLE){
            ps->state[i] = RUNNING;
            return ps->childern[i];
        }else if(ps->state[i] == RUNNING){
            ps->state[i] = RUNNABLE;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
typedef struct {
    /* you should not use global variables. Therefore 
     * you use this structure to retain any context/state your
     * simulator needs between calls. Please add anything you need, and
     * the test code will pass this to your functions
     */
    //int MAX = NPROC;
    int curr;
    processState state[NPROC];
    int childern[NPROC]; //0, 12, 14, 14, 16
    int parentOf[NPROC]; //-1, 0, 1, 1, 3
   
} processStructure;
```

Currently, I am able to run through half of the provided code but now I am getting stuck when a 3rd (0 being the parent) process gets added. I have each process come in as runnable and it changes to RUNNING while calling processTimerInterrupt(); and I understand why this can't work as it is *if 0 is sleeping but 1 is RUNNING and 2 3 is RUNNABLE it will never get to 4 I put myself in an infinite loop per se.* but there are no other functions between adding the 4th process and calling processTimerInterrupt(); on 2 then 3 then 2 then 1 then 2. **(I would show the code but I am not asking anyone to do my homework, just for assistance on this part)** I am not sure if I am messing up by adding a process or missing something important in the function itself. I tried looking everywhere but as a novice to C, everyone uses more complex methods to do an Interrupt which I can not understand and probably not implement correctly.

Comment: I think we need to know more architecture details about your software. Please explain the meaning of the data in your structure `processStructure`. The array `processState state[NPROC];` inside the structure looks suspicious. Shouldn't every process have a single structure each with a single state value? Should there be an array or list of process structures?

Comment: The expression `ps->state[i+1]` will go beyond the end of the array when `i` is `NPROC-1`.

Comment: `ps->state[i+1]` will invoke Undefined Behavior accessing a value outside the array bounds of the `state` array. You are given an interrupt function that is invoked by an interrupt service request. You don't have to worry about how that happens, you just need to write the function to return the specific information requested.

Comment: The instructions say "Returns the PID of the **new** running process", so presumably that means the next process after `curr`. If there is no **new** process after `curr`, then there is no new process running. Adding your `max` or `nprocs` to track the number of processes you are tracking makes sense.

Comment: It is unclear what your goal is. A timer interrupt handler can have many purposes. It seems this one should act as a scheduler for a list of processes determining which process should run in the next time slice, but it is unclear which rules should be applied to determine which process should run next.

Comment: I have ps->state[i+1] because when I add a process I have to make that process come in as runnable, the first process will come in as runnable and I will have no way to make it running it was a lazy way to get through the first set of interrupts.

porcessState stat[NPROC] was my way to hold if that process is sleeping running ready or whatever, and I used a parallel array processState children[NPROC] to find the process ID I asked my professor to see if it was smart they said it would work. while NPROC is just what he defines as the max amount

The goal is confusing I know ;-;

Comment: I use Curr to add the process and its state to the array so yes I can check if Curr is the current running process but each process comes in as "RUNNBLE" so Curr is never running (I do this to for another thing in the test code, its not random). Looking at the test code I have to get a pid with the timer interrupt from 3 then 2 then 3 then 1 then 2, so if I make all of them running after the add somehow I would have no way to get to 2, if I run my for loop backward I get 3 each time, if I run it forwards I get 1 each time, if I change it from running to some other status I can get 4 and 2 agai

Answer (score 0):

```
int processTimerInterrupt(processStructure* ps) {
    int ran = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < NPROC; i++){
        if(ps->state[i] == RUNNING){
            ps->state[i] = RUNNABLE;
            if(NPROC > i && ps->state[i+1] == RUNNABLE){
                ps->state[i+1] = RUNNING;
                return ps->childern[i+1];
                //return ps->childern[i];
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i < NPROC; i++){
    if(ps->state[i] == RUNNABLE){
        ps->state[i] = RUNNING;
        return ps->childern[i];
        }
    }
     return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).